# How to analyze jmeter dashboard report,any open source tool or framework available which helps in analyzing JMeter Dashboard reports after test run?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I found some solution which helps to analyze a single graph.
Free Open source solutions to analyze a single graph...

[JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) - look onto custom graphs in this package;

[JMeter Result Analysis Plugin](https://github.com/afranken/jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin)

[JWeter tool for logs analyzing & visualization](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jweter/overview)

Looking for a solution or open source tool which helps to analyze the [JMeter dashboard report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which having 23 graphs.

Comment: I am trying to implement some tool, feel free to join )
https://github.com/innogames/JMeter-Control-Center

Comment: @v0devil Does you tool analyze the reports to tell where are the issues and contention points ?

Comment: @v0devil  your tool looks like promising and helpful as it covers my requirement as.. "1. Analyzer - build reports, analyze results and compare results with another". Will it provide graphs like those available in JMeter Dashboard reports. In Github it was there but a few only .

Comment: I do not know which default JMeter dashboard is providing. But it has already most of the graphs, tables. If you miss something just create an issue, I will add what you need/desire

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to fully understand the question , but I'll try to answer.

Have you generated the HTML report as described here ?

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

This reports provides the most complete information for analyzing a load test.

Is your question about generating it, in this case I pointed you to the manual.

If not, what is your issue with the HTML report , and why do you write "*some of them provide better results reporting out-of-box than JMeter's original ones*" ?

Since AFAIK, the HTML report provides the same information with even more graphs and dashboards.

**Edit:**

Regarding analysis of the report, this does not exist currently and this is usually the role of a performance/load test expert.
Maybe in the future through IA, that might exist. So for now, try to understand what each graph provides as information and correlate between them, or ask for assistance of a performance tester.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question. I am generating JMeter dashboard report. I need to have a mechanism to analyze the report. Like any open source tool or framework whereas an Input I can pass the report and I will get an analysis of my dashboard report.

Comment: you are 100% correct. This supposes to do by a Performance architect , but my requirement is like if any tool or framework or standard is available which we can try.

Comment: Hello, I don’t know any as of today.

Comment: thanks for your support. Need to use any AI tool for this. If you have any in your mind please suggest. I will start to explore that.

Comment: Frankly it will be a huge piece of work (that’s something that will be probably available in upcoming years bu some software company like us or some competitors ), you’ll go faster by learning how to analyze or ask for expertise.